# Maximo Assetspec automation script slowness and error

Tags: oracle, automation, jython, maximo

Below is my automation script that is the second part of an asset loading process. The first part loads attribute data to the asset upon creation from an external system but it also sets the CLASSIFICATIONID which creates records in the ASSETSPEC table which fires the below script:

```
from psdi.mbo import MboConstants
from psdi.server import MXServer
from psdi.security import UserInfo

username = "maxadmin"

mxServer = MXServer.getMXServer()
userInfo = mxServer.getUserInfo(username)

if mbo != None:
    mxAssetSpec = mbo

    AssetNum = mxAssetSpec.getString("assetnum")
    SiteID = mxAssetSpec.getString("siteid")

    gisAssetSet = mxServer.getMboSet(FEATURECLASS, userInfo)
    gisAssetSet.setWhere("mxassetnum = '" + AssetNum + "' and mxsiteid = '" + SiteID + "'")
    gisAssetSet.reset()

    gis = gisAssetSet.getMbo(0)

    if FEATURECLASS == "GRAVITYSEWERLINES":
        if ASSETATTRID == 'MATERIAL':
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("alnvalue", gis.getString("material"))
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasure", '0')
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasure", gis.getString("length_"))
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasureunitid", 'FT')
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasureunitid", 'FT')
        if ASSETATTRID == 'LENGTH':
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("numvalue", gis.getString("length_"))
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasure", '0')
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasure", gis.getString("length_"))
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasureunitid", 'FT')
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasureunitid", 'FT')
        if ASSETATTRID == 'INSTALL':
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("alnvalue", gis.getString("instalyear"))
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasure", '0')
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasure", gis.getString("length_"))
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasureunitid", 'FT')
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasureunitid", 'FT')
        if ASSETATTRID == 'ESTYEAR':
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("alnvalue", gis.getString("est_year"))
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasure", '0')
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasure", gis.getString("length_"))
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasureunitid", 'FT')
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasureunitid", 'FT')
        if ASSETATTRID == 'PDIAM':
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("numvalue", gis.getString("diameter"))
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasure", '0')
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasure", gis.getString("length_"))
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasureunitid", 'FT')
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasureunitid", 'FT')

    mxAssetSpec.save()
    mxAssetSpec.close()
    mxAssetSpec.resetForRefreshOnSave()

else:
    raise UnboundLocalError
```

There are about 8 classification attributes that it cycles through. The script itself runs very fast but there is a pause of about 3 seconds between each classification attribute. And i also get an oracle error:

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "ASSETNUM": invalid identifier

The only place i am referrencing ASSETNUM is when i am retrieving the string from the ASSETSPEC MBO which assetnum is an attribute of so i am confused why i am getting this error.

My questions are, why am i getting the invalid identifier error and why is there a pause, and are they connected?

The script takes about 20 seconds to complete and works fine but 20 seconds is about 19 seconds too long. Any help would be appreciated. Also any comments on how to improve the code would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
if mbo != None:
mxAssetSpec = mbo

mxAssetSet = mxAssetSpec.getMboSet("ASSET")
mxAsset = mxAssetSet.getMbo(0)
featureclass = mxAsset.getString("PLUSSFEATURECLASS")
assetattrid = mxAssetSpec.getString("ASSETATTRID")

print(featureclass)
print(assetattrid)

if featureclass == "GRAVITYSEWERLINES":
    gisAssetSet = mxAssetSpec.getMboSet("SPATIAL_GRAVITYSEWERLINES")
    gis = gisAssetSet.getMbo(0)
    length = gis.getString("length_")
    if assetattrid == 'MATERIAL':
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("alnvalue", gis.getString("material"))
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasure", '0')
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasure", length)
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasureunitid", 'FT')
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasureunitid", 'FT')
    if assetattrid == 'LENGTH':
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("numvalue", gis.getString("length_"))
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasure", '0')
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasure", length)
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasureunitid", 'FT')
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasureunitid", 'FT')
    if assetattrid == 'INSTALL':
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("alnvalue", gis.getString("instalyear"))
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasure", '0')
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasure", length)
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasureunitid", 'FT')
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasureunitid", 'FT')
    if assetattrid == 'ESTYEAR':
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("alnvalue", gis.getString("est_year"))
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasure", '0')
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasure", length)
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasureunitid", 'FT')
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasureunitid", 'FT')
    if assetattrid == 'PDIAM':
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("numvalue", gis.getString("diameter"))
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasure", '0')
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasure", length)
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasureunitid", 'FT')
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasureunitid", 'FT')

    mxAssetSpec.save()
```

else:
    raise UnboundLocalError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few ideas to improve the performance of your script. I'll give them as general rules and then give examples of how to apply them.

Rule: Don't do in your script what you can make Java do, because compiled Java is faster than your script.

Application: Instead of getting the gisAssetSet from mxserver, I would put a relationship on AssetSpec and use that via mbo.getMboSet("relationship"). This leaves Java to do the string manipulation and the owning transaction to do the saving.

Rule: Set-up and tear-down are expensive, so reduce and avoid them to the extent possible.

Application 1: I'm assuming you're using an Object Launch Point. To the extent possible, use an Object Event Condition to prevent your script from running when it shouldn't. This avoids set up and tear down.

Application 2: Instead of using bind variables on your Launch Point, use mbo.get method. Each bound Launch Point variable results in about 5 extra, related ones which increases setup and teardown time. You can read more about this in [Scripting with Maximo](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=a9ba1efe-b731-4317-9724-a181d6155e3a#fullpageWidgetId=W5f281fe58c09_49c7_9fa4_e094f86b7e98&file=83c7752c-a621-4af9-bb32-d6ba7d612ab2), in the section on implicit variables.

Rule: Don't call mbo.getWhatever() twice for the same attribute.

Application: There are a couple of cases where you make consecutive calls to getString("length_"). I think your code will perform better if you call it once, cache the returned value in a variable, then use that variable multiple times.

As far as the Oracle error you are getting, I feel like I don't have enough information. Are there other scripts or crossovers or etc at play? Rephrased, how do you know this error is being caused by this script?

I hope that helps.

Comment: I added the new code above but it is still about a 3 second pause between each asset spec attribute. The script itself if firing in 16ms but the time between firing for each asset spec attribute is about 3 seconds.

This script is the second part of a load process. The first script copies attribute information and also sets the CLASSIFICATIONID which in turn fires this script.

Comment: Don't call mxAssetSpec.save().

As a rule, you should only call save() on an MboSet if you get the MboSet from MXServer.

Comment: Also, just as a matter of coding style, I would tend to not alias mbo as mxAssetSpec. For me, calling it just "mbo" reminds me that it was supplied by Maximo and may refer to different objects, depending on the Launch Point.

Comment: Thanks, but it still pausing about 3 seconds between each assetattrid. The code itself is running very fast but the system literally seems to pause about 3 seconds between each attribute. It is running through the code for each assetspec attribute. I have a demo system i can test this on as well. I will try that and see if i get the same results

Comment: Is the pause still happening even without the save() call in your code?

Comment: I figured out why it was taking 3 seconds between. It was the condition on the launch point. i had: assetnum in (select assetnum from asset where plussfeatureclass is not null). After i removed that the entire sequence finished in about 1 second.

I also removed the save call but that did not do anything. Removing the object launch condition also removed the ASSETNUM error.

Comment: Doing (assetnum, siteid) in (select assetnum, siteid... might make your condition run faster and will make it more correct. Or correlating it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to rewrite your code, removing the ifs and using elifs instead to reduce redundancy. I would use ASSET as the main mbo if I were in your place though, and use custom getMboSets to reach each ASSETSPEC mbo so as to not run sql commands against the ASSET table 5 times for each SPEC record. If both methods don't work, it is better to run your code at night using an escalation and an action launchpoint.
BTW, you also don't need to run .save() if you're using getMboSets.

```
mxAssetSpec = mbo
mxAsset = mxAssetSpec.getMboSet("ASSET").moveFirst()
featureclass = mxAsset.getString("PLUSSFEATURECLASS")
assetattrid = mxAssetSpec.getString("ASSETATTRID")

if featureclass == "GRAVITYSEWERLINES" and assetattrid in ["MATERIAL","LENGTH","INSTALL","ESTYEAR","PDIAM"]:
    gis = mxAssetSpec.getMboSet("SPATIAL_GRAVITYSEWERLINES").moveFirst()
    if gis is not None:
        length = gis.getString("length_")
        if assetattrid == "MATERIAL":
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("alnvalue", gis.getString("material"))
        elif assetattrid == "LENGTH":
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("numvalue", length)
        elif assetattrid == "INSTALL":
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("alnvalue", gis.getString("instalyear"))
        elif assetattrid == "ESTYEAR":
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("alnvalue", gis.getString("est_year"))
        elif assetattrid == "PDIAM":
            mxAssetSpec.setValue("numvalue", gis.getString("diameter"))
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasure", "0")
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasure", length)
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("startmeasureunitid", "FT")
        mxAssetSpec.setValue("endmeasureunitid", "FT")
```